# Trying to Update In-Process Azure Function to Isolated But Can't Change .NET Version

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I have to update a Function App to target `.NET 7`. I have to change the Function App type from `In-Process` to `Isolated` (more below). It's currently targeting `.NET 6` and although I downloaded the `.NET 7` SDK and can create new projects with it, I can't change the existing Function App from `.NET 6` to `.NET 7`. So, when I open the project properties, `.NET 7` doesn't show up as an option in the **Target Framework** dropdown. I've restarted VS and my machine to no avail.

I read somewhere that it may be because Visual Studio knows the Function is In-Process and can't update to `.NET 7` until the necessary changes have been made (changing `FunctionName` to `Function` etc). I've removed/added the appropriate nuget packages but am wondering if that could be the issue or if I'm missing something more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out my version of Visual Studio 2022 needed to be updated. Hope this helps someone who goes through all the other recommended actions.